# How do I mount my problematic (btrfs?) disc?

Tags: btrfs

I have an old harddrive that I want to check the contents of.
I think it may previously have been part of a BTRFS raid1 setup, now replaced by a larger drive.

When I connect it with a USB-adapter, I get:

```
usb 7-2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=0840
usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 7-2: Product: External
usb 7-2: Manufacturer: Generic
usb 7-2: SerialNumber: 57442D5743414E5532323536
usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host16: usb-storage 7-2:1.0
checking bus 7, device 27: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:05:00.0/usb7/7-2"
bus: 7, device: 27 was not an MTP device
scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  External         1.14 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] 976773167 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page found
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 16:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
```

And

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdf: 465,8 GiB, 500107861504 bytes, 976773167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So far so good. The lack of partitions here is what makes me think it was part of a btrfs raid.

Now the trouble starts:

```
# btrfs device scan
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
ERROR: device scan failed '/dev/sdf' - Device or resource busy
ERROR: error -16 while registering
```

I can't work out what -16 means. Neither google, nor a grep through the btrfs source files find me any hint at all.

Lets try mounting it:

```
# mount -o degraded /dev/sdf btrfs_test/
mount: /dev/sdf is already mounted or /tmp/btrfs_test busy
```

That's odd, where is it mounted then?

```
# mount | grep sdf
# lsof | grep sdf
# lsof | grep btrfs_test
# fuser -vm /dev/sdf
# grep /tmp/btrfs_test /proc/mounts
# findmnt | grep sdf
# ls -l /sys/block/sdf/holders/
total 0
```

No output at all from any of the commands, expect the 0 count from ls.

Comment: Did anything more appear in kernel logs after `btrfs device scan`?

Comment: @TNW No, nothing at all is written to the logs when I run the scan.

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to assume that (whyever) "/dev/sdf is already mounted or /tmp/btrfs_test busy"? What is the output of `grep /tmp/btrfs_test /proc/mounts` and of `fuser -vm /dev/sdf`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Neither of those return anything at all. `cat /proc/mounts` gives pretty much the same output as just `mount`, and there's no trace of btrfs_test or sdf in there.

Comment: @user50849 What about `ls -l /sys/block/sdf/holders/`?

Comment: try `findmnt|grep` instea of `mount|grep` - mount doesnt always list the device name

Comment: @HaukeLaging I've added that bit as well, thought it was empty as well. That's the case however even for things that are mounted, but I'm not sure what to make of that. sdc is currently mounted, and sdc/holders was empty as well.

Comment: @user50849 The holders are not mounts but other block devices which use this one (like device mapper). Run `strace -f btrfs device scan` and try to find the error which (probably) causes the error message.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I did that, and found something about /dev/btrfs-control, which may have been relevant. Anyway, I just tried upgrading to the recently released 4.4 kernel, and now mounting works just fine. So kernel bug perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the disc was indeed originally part of a raid.

Because other discs, that are still part of that raid are mounted, btrfs becomes confused, thinking that the disc is already mounted, because it's raid is.